# Blender 2.59 incorrect blending

Tags: 3d-graphics, 3d-modeling, blender, transparency

I'm having problems with blender transparency. I want to create a simple 2d character with the transparent body and transparent eyes on it. All objects should be textured. Here is the image for my problem: http://postimage.org/image/7rmglejo/

Right eye is selected - then it blends ok (the right eye looks as I want). But if I deselect - it looks like left eye. So it's blending with the grey color of the background instead of a monster's body.

What is the problem?

Comment: Does this problem occur in the final render? GLSL might not give the correct results for what you're trying to do, but the final render might?  Also, can you post your blend file somewhere?

Comment: @deltaray: http://www.mediafire.com/?do6uq77vc8bnp8v - it's the link for downloading. When rendering everything is ok, but it is comfortable to work this case